# How do you deal with multiple types of the same many-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm wondering if there's a best practice when it comes to having multiple many-to-many relationships between the same tables.

Currently I have a many-to-many relationship between `user` and `item` for the items that users have created.

```
---------------------
| user_id | item_id |
---------------------
| 1       | 3       |
---------------------
```

I'd like to create another junction table for `user` and `item` to reference their watchlist. Should I create separate many-to-many tables?

```
user_item_inventory      user_item_watchlist
---------------------    ---------------------
| user_id | item_id |    | user_id | item_id |
---------------------    ---------------------
| 1       | 3       |    | 2       | 3       |
---------------------    ---------------------
```

OR should I create one many-to-many table that has a many-to-one relationship with a `user_item_type` table?

```
user_item                          user_item_type
-------------------------------    ------------------
| user_id | item_id | type_id |    | id | name      |
-------------------------------    ------------------
| 1       | 3       | 1       |    | 3  | inventory | 
-------------------------------    ------------------
| 2       | 3       | 2       |    | 2  | watchlist | 
-------------------------------    ------------------
```

Comment: I would create separate many-to-many tables, and then if I needed items off both lists use a select distinct union.

Comment: I think it may depend on if user_item tends to grow..If it tends to grow you may want to separete them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the decision ultimately rests on just how conceptually different inventory and wishlists are, based on prior experience, I would suggest using separate tables.

Currently, you have no additional data attached to either the inventory or watchlist, but that will not necessarily be the case in the future. Without knowing more details about the inventory and watchlist, it's hard to make predictions, but as soon as you want to start tracking additional data on an `inventory` relation vs. a `watchlist` relation, having separate tables will make things *much* simpler. As soon as you want to add columns that *only* pertain to one of your types of association, you'll want to have separate tables.

As has been pointed out in the other answer, having separate tables is certainly faster from a pure data storage and retrieval standpoint: you'll have one less column/index to populate/filter by. And if your inventory/wishlist associations table becomes "large", those extra `type_id` references will start to add up to something significant. (It won't matter for smaller sizes, but besides the obvious disk storage factors, more data requires more memory and more cache to manage, especially when indexes are involved.)

Separate tables would be a complication if you need to know *all* the items a user has an interest in (the combination of inventory, watchlist, and any other similar tables you might create), but if that is an actual need, then you could generate that list easily with a `UNION` query on all of the tables. (You could even create another table that contains a copy of all the user - item references as a performance enhancement if necessary.)

Comment: your first point is excellent, in the future there may be more data to store with that specific relationship type. Having separate tables is more future-proof in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

It depens on how do you want to use these data. If they are logically separated and there is no releations between them, then you can use two tables.
If you're going to display inventory and watchlist records, in some module, and you want only distinguish type of records, then you can use one table with type of record.

It is clear that for database engine, it is better to do

```
SELECT * FROM user_item_inventory
```

reather than

```
SELECT * FROM user_item WHERE type_id = 1
```